# Oracle Custom Sort Needed

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql

I have a PLSQL procedure that accepts a parameter.  The data looks like this:

```
11035,15005,17060,17005,17010,15030,15035,11040,15040,15045,14010
```

I need to sort the results in the same order as the parameters passed in.  So, I created some code that will create a dynamic string like this:

```
0:11035,1:15005,2:17060,3:17005,4:17010,5:15030,6:15035,7:11040,8:15040,9:15045,10:14010
```

I thought I could sort by the sequence number preceding each parameter value, but it is not working.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Sort which results? You would probably need to show us the actual query (or a representative example that demonstrates what you are trying to do).

Comment: Is the number of parameters fixed? How are they passed? A comma-separated string? An array?

Answer (score 0):

```
select LISTAGG(xxx, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY xxx)
from
(
select regexp_substr('11035,15005,17060,17005,17010,15030,15035,11040,15040,15045,14010','[^,]+', 1, level) as xxx 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('11035,15005,17060,17005,17010,15030,15035,11040,15040,15045,14010', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
;
```

Comment: That did not work.   My result value is:  11035,11040,14010,15005,15030,15035,15040,15045,17005,17010,17060.   I need them in the original order.........

Answer (score 0):

```
select LISTAGG(xxx, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) as v_data
from
(
select rownum-1 || ':' || regexp_substr('11035,15005,17060,17005,17010,15030,15035,11040,15040,15045,14010','[^,]+', 1, level) as xxx 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('11035,15005,17060,17005,17010,15030,15035,11040,15040,15045,14010', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
;
```

RESULT V_DATA: 0:11035,1:15005,2:17060,3:17005,4:17010,5:15030,6:15035,7:11040,8:15040,9:15045,10:14010

Comment: Hmm, when I run it, it complains that it wants the WITHIN clause:   ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword

Comment: Sr, What is the version database do you using?

Comment: I have updated more within-group above, let try it again and update the result.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be working.   I'd like to understand how this functions with CONNECT BY.   Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: One other question, can this combined with other items in that query?   Example:  SELECT name, email, id.............ORDER BY {your logic here}

Comment: Connect By is used in a hierarchical query command 

Reference documents: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-sequence-of-numbers-in-sql-using-level/#:~:text=LEVEL%20must%20be%20used%20with,database%20along%20with%20data%20dictionary.

And you totally can use it to combine with other items in the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223710/discussion-between-landon-statis-and-hung-le).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
with datum as (select '0:11035,1:1500,2:17060,3:17005,4:17010,5:15030,10:15035,7:11040,8:15040,9:15045,6:14010' as str from dual),
cols as (SELECT LEVEL AS id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
         FROM datum
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL),
output as (select REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^:]+', 1, 2) param_col, 
                  cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[^:]+', 1, 1) as number) order_col
                  from cols)
select param_col
from output
order by order_col
```

Ideally, map this to a Type in Oracle, maybe Params Type, that stores the row-number and the param-value and then pass that between Procs.

For API's let the Java or any API use the LinkedHashMap while creating the Type in the layer, to preserve the insertion order.